# WS_FTP PRO wsftppro.exe command line using Connection Configuration

Tags: ftp-client

I am trying to create BAT file to run WS_FTP PRO wsftppro.exe command line using Connection Configuration. I save Connection Configuration is working in the UI, however, when trying to call it in windows command prompt it fails.

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12\wsftppro.exe" -s "local:c:\FTP\CLIENT\CLIENTS.C0000" -d "CJ PRODUCTION UPLOAD:INTAKE.UP.CLIENTS.C0000"
```

**Error log:**  Use MVS Dsname conventions

I have also tried using single quotes:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12\wsftppro.exe" -s "local:c:\FTP\CLIENT\CLIENTS.C0000" -d "CJ PRODUCTION UPLOAD:'INTAKE.UP.CLIENTS.C0000'"
```

**Error log:**  Remote path not found

How can create a BAT file to run WS_FTP PRO wsftppro.exe command line using Connection Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The single quote is required for the remote dir path to be valid.
The single quote is only used once, **no closing single quote**.

[image]

```
-s "local:c:\FTP\CLIENT\CLIENTS.C0000" -d "CJ PRODUCTION UPLOAD:'INTAKE.UP.CSSCE.CLIENTS.C0000"
```

Powershell code to run it:

```
$args = @"
-s "local:c:\FTP\CLIENT\CLIENTS.C0000" -d "CJ PRODUCTION UPLOAD:'INTAKE.UP.CSSCE.CLIENTS.C0000"
"@
Start-Process "c:\Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12\wsftppro.exe" $args
```